# Network connection slow, one-way, between Ubuntu and Mac OS

Tags: networking, subnet, mac, ubuntu-18.04

I'm stumped.

I have three nodes -- 2 iMacs and 1 Ubuntu 18.04 server -- all on the same subnet.  When I send files, e.g. scp, from Ubuntu to Mac it's relatively fast (5mb/s - not lightning but acceptable).  But, sending files from the Macs to the Ubuntu server, e.g. scp, it's very slow (20k/s).  More specifically, it starts around 1mb/s, but slows to that 20k/s crawl.

The same iMacs, scp-ing a file to another Ubuntu server on a different subnet, is as fast as expected (64mb/s+).

The iMacs are different OS X versions (Mojave on one, slightly older versions on others), with the older one being minimally configured in any way.

How could I begin to diagnose this?  Any help or insight would be appreciated.

**Update**: For what it's worth, transfer is slow between iMacs as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problems before, and it turned out to be speed mismatch between the network port and the adapter ethernet port on the server.  In my case, I was using 'auto' speed negogation but the switch port was fixed by direct switch configuration.

Comment: This is intriguing @mdpc, how might I test this?  I have access to all 3 nodes/servers, but they are at my workplace and all route to -- what I'm assuming is a switch -- I don't have physical access to.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You'd need to have a network person verify the settings on the switch port being used.  AND you'd have to verify the settings on the server side.

Comment: Three other things that I was thinking about: 1. the cable (try switching the cables), 2. failure in the adapter port (try another if available), and 3. switch port is bad (try by swapping the connections between two of the servers, if the problem moves the the connection that is bad....you have an answer)